# Volume setting isn't remembered after restart/shutdown

Tags: sound, startup

This is my first time here and I'm new to linux and also to Ubuntu.
I've installed first version 11.10 and there was some problems with the unity dock and also the problem with the volume not being remembered after restart or shutdown.

I'm using dualboot with Windows 7. Ubuntu was installed after windows. I have 2 sound cards. One is onboard, on the motherboard, and the other is external, an E-MU 0404 USB 2.0 sound card. The last one is my primary sound card and I've choosed it as default output sound card. I've upgraded to 12.04 hopeing that this was fiex but even in this version the OS doesn't keep the volume where it was last time.

The big problem is that sometimes I forget about this problem and start music and it starts at full volume and soon I think I will die of heart attack.

Is there a way to make it remember or at least to tell him to start at a specific volume not at 100%?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of `System Settings` > `Sound`

Comment: Here it is the screenshot: http://s18.postimage.org/fahn8a1nb/Screenshot_from_2012_04_15_21_03_14.png

Comment: There was a fix couple of days ago that solved my sound problem. It was always getting muted after reboot. Install all available updates for 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

A little over a year ago I was having this same issue. My boss told me to set the sound via alsamixer and that fixed it somehow. Worth a shot.

In a terminal run:

```
alsamixer
```

[image]