# How to automatically change the volume after Pulse Audios starts?

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, volume-control

I am suffering from the problem described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122341/volume-setting-isnt-remembered-after-restart-shutdown) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436594/everytime-i-start-ubuntu-or-change-sound-settings-my-volume-is-put-to-100), which unfortunately still hasn't been fixed. Basically after rebooting my computer my volume is at 100% until I trigger the volume. What I mean by this is that the software volume indicator is showing the setting that was set before (e.g. 20%) however the actual sound will be played at 100% until I move the slider a bit and the system "realises" what the volume setting is. I am using an external DAC (which is like a USB soundcard) which is a Schiit Audio.

As a workaround I'm trying to trigger the volume by adding the following command to the startup applications list (Session and Startup) as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448593/pulseaudio-resets-volume-control-to-100-doesnt-save-volume?rq=1):

```
pacmd set-sink-volume 2 20000
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, possibly because the Pulse Audio System is not running yet when the command is executed. I've tried sleeping before executing it, but that doesn't help either; moreover I want to have a guarantee that the volume has been set properly so that I don't have to live a stressful life ;)

I've tried renaming my task so that it is at the end of the list to no avail.

Is there any other way for me to set the volume automatically after Pulse Audio loads? I don't want to get a heart attack every time I forget to retrigger the volume after login...

I am using Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I've just changed my `default.pa` and added the command there a second ago and will reboot now to see if it helps. That module is loaded, yes.

Comment: @Takkat: Ok, that worked. I did change it before you've suggested it but if you want you can post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pulseaudio module responsible to restore any device's volume to values before rebooting is the `module-device-restore`. If restoring devices does not work as expected  we may want to check if that module was loaded with:

```
pacmd list-modules
```

If it was not there we should add the module to our `default.pa` settings file. This file is located in `/etc/pulse` by default but we can have an additinal per-user `default.pa` overriding this in `~/.pulse/` or in `~/.config/pulse/`. When editing make sure you choose the appropriate file, and make a backup beforehand.

To load `module-device-restore` on starting the pulseaudio sound server the following line has to be included (or uncommented) in the `default.pa`:

```
load-module module-device-restore
```