# Audio unmutes when coming out of suspend in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: sound, 14.04, laptop, suspend

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, whenever I wake my laptop out of suspend, its previous volume settings are forgotten and the volume is unmuted and set to 100%. Obviously, this is annoying if I open my laptop in a public space. This also occurs whenever I turn my laptop on (i.e. it doesn't remember that I turned it off with its volume controls muted). What should I modify so that my laptop remembers its pre-suspend volume settings?

Edit: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr on a Dell Inspiron N5110.

Comment: This may help [How to automatically change the volume after Pulse Audios starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457868/how-to-automatically-change-the-volume-after-pulse-audios-starts)

Comment: Unfortunately, in my `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, I already have the line `load-module module-device-restore`. I'm not sure why the module isn't setting the system volume accordingly, but I'd rather not set it to be muted by default when I open my laptop if I can instead restore its proper functionality.

Comment: @MichaelLee If you dual boot with Windows 8, [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/464444/258567). If headphones work, and the speaker doesn't work or works intermittently, please click "Does this bug affect you?" in the upper left of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020).