# Volume level not remembered after shutdown/restart

Tags: brightness, volume-control

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the volume level always starts at 100% when I turn on the computer. 
Is there a way for the volume level of the previews session be remembered in the new session? (and can the brightness level also be remembered?)

Comment: This may be your issue too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457868/how-to-automatically-change-the-volume-after-pulse-audios-starts

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem in your pulseaudio settings. Try renaming the ~/.pulse directory:

```
mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulsebak
```

Then reboot, and see if it helps.

Comment: If a reboot really necessary? Just re-login might be quicker.

Comment: Perhaps, I don't think it should make that much of a difference in time or effect.

Comment: When I run that command in the terminal I get this: 
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/jmrf/.pulse’: No such file or directory

Comment: Turns out my pulse folder was in .config folder. I did what you said, but it just works 1 time when I restart (the volume at the login it's the same as it was in the last session, but only for that occasion), then I'm back to square one, and again the sound volume is not saved.

Comment: Warning: If you use the equaliser, this will reset your equaliser settings.